# Oracle Reports 6i Using Ampersand Sign to Reference Fields In Report Layout

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I am creating a report using Oracle 6i usually for formatting purposes i can reference a field name in an label item. This makes the value of the item look like part of the label, its really nice feature for layout.

An example of what i am saying is if you have a field 'username' on the report i can use '&username' caption inside a label item '**Last User Logged In : &username**' and it will be displayed as **Last User Logged In : devdar**.

The issue i am having is i have an item on the report which is an image however i cannot use the ampersand sign to reference the display value of the image. How is this done ? I am getting the following when i use it as **Last User Logged In : &username**

**Output:**

**Last User Logged In : &username**

Comment: You need to show the image as part of the label?

Comment: yes i need to since the entire report is inside a label and all other fields are displayed by using reference(&) and that information i would like to display falls inside the label content.

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but maybe you can try this:
- Create a formula field, with File Format = image. It should return the file path of the image. Use the ampersand sign to reference it.

Comment: The image is stored in the database and no formula fields will return blob they only return Number, Char, and Date. So that option may not work for me. Hope i understood what you were trying to say.

Comment: I guess you understood. 
I don't know how to help you right now, so I'll just upvote your question and check it later.